# MLOps - How to refresh a ML model

Tags: machine-learning, kubernetes, model, microservices, mlops

The image below show the two pipelines that we have in my company to manage the life cycle of a model.

[image]

- The first pipeline, "Application", relates to the creation of the application component that host the model and has the inference logic.
- The second, that of "Model", is a pipeline that leads to the generation of the model in binary format.

Together (model and application) will be deployed in our orchestrator (a kubernetes cluster).

[image]

I am in a situation where the application logic does not change but the models do.
I could find myself in the situation below.

[image]

I suppose there are two approach to manage the runtime model refresh on the orchestrator (hope someone suggests me other possibilities that I haven't thought about):

1. In the application logic; The code manages the refresh through a thread by taking the new model.

   - *Pros*: A new container is not generated
   - *Cons*: Ability to introduce a bug.
2. Through the pipeline; The pipeline must be triggered by an event (in my case a merge on a git branch) and bring the container by performing a rolling update. The new container at run will load the new model.

   - *Pros*: Existing process
   - *Cons*: Each new version of the model should provide for a new build of the container, even if the application logic has not changed.

[**Question**]
Are there any best practices for these cases (perhaps through a system of tags on the images) that someone can suggest me?

Thank you
Kipliko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most seamless way is to do a [rolling update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/) via k8s/kubectl. This will require a new container, however, this is considered a best practice, as each container stays atomic and reproducible. Updating the model via threads would be difficult to debug.

Another scenario you could do is [blue-green deployment](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/continuous-blue-green-deployments-with-kubernetes) using Istio, and slowly move traffic between the old and new model, although this would require a bit more overhead.